# Finding Jordan Canonical form given the minimal and characteristic polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

I have the following information: the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $p_A(t)=(t-4)^3(t+6)^2$ and the minimal polynomial is $q_A(t)=(t-4)^2(t+6).$

I'm having problems seeing how one would work backwards with just this information.

My attempt at JCF.

$\begin{pmatrix}
4&1&0&0&0\\
0&4&0&0&0\\
0&0&4&0&0\\
0&0&0&-6&0\\
0&0&0&0&-6\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: NB in general the minimal and characteristic polynomials of a matrix do not determine its Jordan form uniquely. For example, there are two Jordan matrices $J$ (up to rearrangement) for which $p_A(t) = t^4$ and $m_A(t) = t^2$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The multiplicity of an eigenvalue as a root of the characteristic polynomial is the size of the block with that eigenvalue in the Jordan form. The size of the largest sub-block (Elementary Jordan Block) is the multiplicity of that eigenvalue as a root of the minimal polynomial.

Can you see how this determines the matrix?

Added: For example, the block with the eigenvalue $4$ in its diagonal must be $3\times3$, since that is the multiplicity of $3$ as a root of $p_A$. We also know by the definition of the Jordan form that this block is made up by smaller sub-blocks, each with $4$ in its diagonal and $1$s above, and with decreasing size as one goes down left to right.

Now, without any further information, since the larger block is of size $3\times 3$, there are three possibilities for our subblocks:

- Three sub-blocks of $1 \times 1$, giving the following large block: $\left (\begin{matrix}4&0&0 \\0&4&0 \\0&0&4\end{matrix} \right )$
- One subblock of size two, and since the other must not be bigger and their sizes must "add up" to $3 \times 3$ we get: $\left (\begin{matrix}4&1&0 \\0&4&0 \\0&0&4\end{matrix} \right )$.
- A single large block: $\left (\begin{matrix}4&1&0 \\0&4&1 \\0&0&4\end{matrix} \right )$

But we know that the dimension of the largest sub-block must be the multiplicty of $4$ as a root of the minimal polynomial, hence the only possibility is: $$  \left (\begin{matrix}4&1&0 \\0&4&0 \\0&0&4\end{matrix} \right )$$

Comment: I have a matrix that is the eigenvalues on the diagonal, 1's above the eigenvalues, and zeroes everywhere else.  I sort of see this relationship.

Comment: I added to my original answer how to figure out the form of the block with $4$s in its diagonal.

Comment: I put an attempt above.

Comment: Your attempt is correct :) I'm assuming you used that the multiplicty of $-6$ as a root of the minimal is $1$ and hence there are two sub-blocks of sizes $1\times 1$ each.

Comment: I was very tempted to stick a 1 in the lower part of that matrix.  It took me a *rather long* moment to make the connection.  Your prompts were very helpful.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. If you're happy with the answer, feel free to accept it so others can see that is has been resolved.