# Some confusion regarding Jordan block form of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, jordan-normal-form

I am given that a $5\times 5$ matrix over the field of complex numbers has characteristic polynomial $f=(x-2)^3(x+7)^2$ and minimal polynomial $p=(x-2)^2(x+7)$. From this, and this other [Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213788/finding-jordan-canonical-form-given-the-minimal-and-characteristic-polynomial), I have deduced that the JCF for this matrix is given by, $$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -7 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -7\end{bmatrix}.$$ However, in [some literature](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~scott/mat310.spr05/hw/solution11.pdf) the JCF is given as, $$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -7 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -7\end{bmatrix},$$ with the only difference being the position of the $1$. Are both correct? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the two forms are both valid as also the following for example

$$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -7 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -7\end{bmatrix}\quad \begin{bmatrix}-7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -7 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}.
$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -7 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -7\end{bmatrix}\quad \begin{bmatrix}-7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -7 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Can you give an explanation please?

Comment: Is there in general a formula to compute the number of possible Jordan forms for a given matrix?

Comment: The Jordan form is unique up to the permutations of the blocks and the choiche of the upper or lower superdiagonal.

Comment: @quanticbolt see the related https://mathoverflow.net/questions/100457/number-of-jordan-canonical-forms-for-an-nxn-matrix